# Error:Could not run build action using Gradle installation

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am new to Android Studio. I have installed the newest version of Android Studio 1.1.0. I can't build my gradle project. I am using JDK 7. The folder .gradle is in the directory

> C:\Users[Username].gradle

And the installation of Android Studio and Android SDK is in my another partition.

On build I got this error

> Error:Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'F:\AndroidStudio\gradle\gradle-2.2.1'.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Goto Setting->Gradle->Enable Offline Mode and put local gradle directory here..

Comment: It's already set the local gradle directory

Comment: Post you gradle file , or try to add classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0' to your project top directory gradle

Answer (score 2):

We have two famous way for this problem:

**1- update the gradle:**

*step 1:*

Get latest version supported by Android Studio from:

[http://www.gradle.org/downloads](http://gradle.org/gradle-download/)

(Currently 2.7 [is NOT supported by Android Studio yet] on the Bottom right choose your gradle version that you want to download (at the moment is 2.4 link:https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip))

*step 2:*

Extract the gradle file and install to dists folder(gradle folder): default location is: C:\Users[username]\gradle\wrapper\dists

*step 3:*

Open Android Studio: File/Settings/Gradle/Service directory path: (Change to folder you set above) and Click ok.

Status on bottom should indicate it's busy & error should be fixed.

*step 4:*

restart Android Studio

**2- Delete the .gradle folder:**

default location is:

C:\Users[username]\gradle\wrapper\dists

after that open Android Studio and make a new project (might need to reastart).

Answer (score 0):

After much google'ing and trying lots of different suggestions, removing ~/.gradle and followng the first answer posted here, it finally sync'ed and built. Starting off clean and using a local gradle location was the trick.